# Evaluating a multiple != if statement in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, equals

```
elif S[i - 1:i + 2] != S[i] * 3 != S[i - 2:i + 1]: return False
```

How does this (if) statement in python evaluate?

Is it or or xor?

Do they all have to be equal?

Comment: `a != b != c` evaluates as `a != b and b != c`.

Comment: that didnt seem to be written in any documentation anywhere. thanks

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons